# Operator overload in UML diagram

Tags: c++, uml, operator-overloading

Is there any specific way to represent operator overloading in UML. E.g. I have the following:

```
virtual MyClass& operator= (const MyClass& right) = 0;
```

Can I assume that it can be represented as a normal function in UML, where the operator name is `=`, the input parameter is `(const MyClass& right)` and the return type is `MyClass&` ?.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Even if one could represent anything using UML, IMO for software engineering UML models should be used to represent the software design. It is pointless (and a big misusage) trying to represent the exact code implementation in a UML model. Operator overloading is an implementation details that should not be shown in a UML design.

Comment: I wouldn't agree less with you @greydet. However in our enterprise they are using overloaded operators to perform complex and intensive binary data synchronization and it is important for us to show the complex class structure + the overridden operators. That is the only reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I found the solution by going back to my UML university notes :) (besides I'm happy to confirm that after so many years, university notes are still very valuable and always good to have! Never throw them away).

The `virtual`is considered to be a Stereotype.
The operation/function name will be `operator=`
The return type will be `MyClass&`
The argument name will be `right` with a type of `const MyClass&`

To recap, the full UML notation should be as follows:

```
<<virtual>> operator=(right:const MyClass&):MyClass&
```

Comment: can you help me with this 
std::map< imsi , SmcManager * > sessions_map_;
how to map this in class diagram?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nostradamus' answer:

If you wish to add cast operators to your classes/structs:

```
operator int32_t() { return id; }
```

You can type the following as UML:

```
int32_t(): operator
```

as a type of hack. The generated code will look very similar to the example at the top of this answer.